# New pin to quick access in file Explorer from a file

Tags: powershell, explorer

Has a script that makes new pin to quick access in file Explorer from a file

Here is the script:

```
#New pin to quick access in file Explorer from a file
$ShortcutsFile = 'H:\_ProfilBackup\Genveje.txt'
$listFile = Get-Content $ShortcutsFile

$o = new-object -com shell.application -Verbose

foreach ($line in Get-Content $ShortcutsFile) {
    if ($line -match $regex) {
        $o.Namespace($line).Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome")
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why it works?

I'm a little confused about the line:

```
foreach ($line in Get-Content $ShortcutsFile) {
if ($line -match $regex)
```

Have tried other ways to read the content from a file.

But then it only works if there is only one line in the file.

I can only make it work with multiple lines from a file if I use the above script

Comment: Where does $regex get set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a file, you either have to loop as the post shows, or you bring it in raw. If you are trying to process many pins, that means looping. Which is all that line is doing.

```
$regex
```

Is just a variable that has some string to compare against for true or false, but you don't show that part of the code.

```
# Read the shortcuts file, one line at a time, to the end of the file
# If any line read, matches the regex string, do something with that match
foreach ($line in Get-Content $ShortcutsFile) {
if ($line -match $regex)
```

### Update for the OP

Really regarding your post and use case, it can be tweaked to this.

```
# What is in the file
Get-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\QuickLinks.txt'

c:\scripts
C:\techtools
c:\temp


$ShellObj = New-Object -ComObject shell.application -Verbose
ForEach ($line in (Get-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\QuickLinks.txt')) 
{$ShellObj.Namespace($line).Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome")}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Is it possible that you can show another way to do New pin to quick access in file Explorer using Get-Content from a file?

Comment: that is, the file contains links to folders that you would like to add to quick access in file Explorer